# Как обновить версию Python в "Ubuntu on Windows"?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu

В bash оболочке на windows питон имеет версию 3.5.2, есть ли возможность установить последнюю версию 3.6.3?

Через команду `sudo apt-get upgrade` были обновления, но версия осталась прежняя, только дата поменялась на сентябрьскую:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
```

Попробовал `sudo apt-get install python3` пишет что уже установлена новейшая версия (3.5.1-3), если явно указать версию пишет что пакет не найден:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Новые версии `python` не сразу попадают в официальные репозитории. Вы можете добавить [ppa репозиторий](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) и произвести установку оттуда:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3.6
```

Также можно собрать необходимую версию из [исходников](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/).

Comment: Получилось. Большое спасибо! Подскажите еще пожалуйста, как установить ссылку чтобы по команде `python3` запускалась версия 3.6 а не старая?

Comment: @AlexDivola [How to make python3 command run Python 3.6 instead of 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43743654/6166540)

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!